# In a multi-dimensional data array, which parts should be interpreted as the "random variables"?

Tags: random-variable, dataset

**Disclaimer:** I am very much a beginner, so this question is probably confusingly written. Please bear with me.

**Background:** I have a three-dimensional array of data, which was collected from a series of experiments on biological cells. The dimensions are the following.

- Time: representing seconds at which observations were made, ranging from 1 to 5000
- Individual trials: representing various experimental conditions under which observations were made, ranging from 1 to 50
- Individual cells: representing various cells whose behavior was observed, ranging from 1 to 10

So, the point (1, 1, 1) represents the value that was observed at the first second, under the first of 50 different conditions, at the first of 10 cells. In total, there are $5000 \times 50 \times 10 = 2.5$ million measurements.

**Question:** With the goal of performing some statistical analyses on these data, I would like to understand which parts of the array are my "random variables". Are the variables each of the three dimensions, i.e. time, trials, and cells? This doesn't seem to be a useful interpretation, because the measurements themselves (i.e. the *points* represented by an index into each of the time, trial, *and* cell dimensions) are what seem like the meaningful parts.

For example, I'd like to find a covariance matrix for these data. I believe that the covariance matrix would be given by the formula $$S = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})(X_i - \bar{X})^T$$

It's clear to me how to calculate $\bar{X}$, but what are the $X_i$ in a data array such as this one?

I'm probably all sorts of mixed up here, but I'd appreciate any guidance that you may be able to provide.